# How can I remove specific words from a string - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, dictionary, select

I have the following string, from which I want to extract any 'words' which do not contain numbers or special characters. For now, commas, question marks or full stops are accepted:

`b? Dl )B 4(V! A. MK, YtG ](f 1m )CNxuNUR {PG?`

Desired output:

`b? Dl A. MK, YtG`

`5`

Current output:

`b? Dl A. MK, YtG 1m`

`6`

At the moment, the function below successfully removes numbers from the string, however, words which include both numbers and letters are not omitted. Thus, the '1m' being included in my current output.

Current function:

```
def howMany(sentence)

    if sentence.is_a? String
        
        output = sentence.split
        count = 0

        test_output = []

        output.each {|word| 

            if word !~ /\D/ || word =~ /[!@#$%^&*()_+{}\[\]:;'"\/\\><]/
                count
            else
                test_output.push(word)
                count += 1
            end

        }   

        puts test_output 
        puts count 
    
    else
        puts "Please enter a valid string" 
    end

end
```

My assumption is I'll have to somehow iterate through each word in the string in order to find whether it includes numbers, however, I'm not sure how to go about that specific solution. I thought about using `.split("")` inside my `output.each` function but was unsuccessful after a few attempts.

Any suggestions would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just deleted a question of yours with an answer. Although the system lets you do that, if it is a reasonable answer then that is frowned upon for wasting answerer efforts. (But code-only answers are frowned upon as poor.) Also non-positively scored posts count towards asking limits even when deleted. Research how the site works. [Help] [meta] [meta.se] For code questions give a [mre]. Research issues before considering posting, including googling with 'site:stackoverflow.com'. [ask] Hope you don't mind my posting here. (Can't comment on a deleted post.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `String#scan` using a regular expression.

```
str = "b? Dl )B 4(V! A. MK, YtG ](f 1m )CNxuNUR {PG?"
```

```
str.scan(/(?<!\S)[a-z.,\?\r\n]+(?!\S)/i)
  #=> ["b?", "Dl", "A.", "MK,", "YtG"]
```

[Ruby demo](https://rubular.com/r/ucVaskRvG4XsGs) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/7Zse5u/1)

I've included the link to *regex101.com*, a popular site for testing regular expressions, because it provides extensive information, in particular, by hovering over each element of the expression one can obtain an explanation of its function. (By hovering the cursor, that is.) As that site does not support Ruby's regex engine (*Onigmo* for v2.0+), I've selected the PCRE regex engine, which in this case gives the same result as does Ruby's engine.

---

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing mode* to make it self-documenting.

```
/
(?<!\S)         # negative lookbehind asserts that the following match is
                # not preceded by a character other than a whitespace
[a-z.,\?\r\n]+  # match one or more of the indicated characters
(?!\S)          # negative lookahead asserts that the previous match is
                # not followed by a character other than a whitespace
/ix             # case-insensitive and free-spacing regex definition modes
```

---

Alternatively, to avoid the need for the negative lookbehind and negative lookahead, one could split on whitespace and then select:

```
a.select { |s| s.match?(/\A[a-z.,\?\r\n]+\z/i) }
  #=> ["b?", "Dl", "A.", "MK,", "YtG"]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help here Cary! I had found a solution prior to reading this, but will most certainly look further into your answer and the resources you've provided regarding regular expressions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying something like this.

Turn the sentence into an array using split `sentence.split(' ')`.
Then allow only the ones that match the pattern using `filter`
Then use the filtered list for both puts operations. It should look something like this.

```rb
def how_many(sentence)
  sentence.split(' ').filter { |word| matches_pattern?(word) }.tap do |words|
    puts words.size
    puts words # or words.join(' ')
  end
end

def matches_pattern?(word)
  word.matches? /some_regular_expression/
end
```

You can of course modify accordingly to add any side cases, et c.
This would be a more idiomatic solution.

Note than you can also use `.filter(&method(:matches_pattern?))` but that might be confusing to some.

**Edit**: rubular.com is a good place to try your regexps.

**Edit**: when things get hard, try making them in smaller chunks (i.e. try not to make methods longer than 5 lines).

Comment: Thank you for your help mate. I ended up going on rubular.com and turns out all I had to do was change ```word !~ /\D/``` to ```word !~ /\d/``` LOL. I thought they were the same but D denotes Any-non digit while d denotes Any-digit. I'll definitely play around with some of the stuff you've included in your answer though. Thanks again!